# Jenkins add additional info in stage cells/boxes and not just the default build duration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a deploy job which has a drop-down of build jobs to select. How can I add additional info (eg. build number, image tag) in the stage cells or boxes? [image]